# Могут ли вставные конструкции выделяться с помощью запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Какие? И самое главное - почему?

Answer (score 2):

Лопатин не допускает, Розенталь допускает, если вставная конструкция короткая и попутное замечание носит характер пояснения какого-то слова в основном предложении:

В редких случаях вставная конструкция выделяется запятыми: Мне показалось даже, а может быть оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее (Акс.); Экспонаты Биологического музея, а их свыше двух тысяч, рассказывают о животном мире нашей планеты (Газ.)
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123

Зато Лопатин говорит о едином знаке "запятая и тире":
Примечание 2. При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания: Вы садитесь в коляску, — это так приятно после вагона, — и катите по степной дороге (Ч.). Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126

Answer (score 0):

Какие? **И самое главное ― почему?**

Вводное сочетание **"и самое главное"** чаще обособляется с помощью тире изи запятой, иногда ставится двоеточие.

**И самое главное** ― ссылаются ли на него другие блогеры? И самое главное — он снят в России!

**И самое главное**, планета лишилась воды и превратилась в безводную, выжженную пустыню.

**И самое главное**: они нашли здесь то, чего искали?